# How to dynamically change the css style in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically change the css padding. So every tenth number, I want to increase the padding. Here is my code

```js
    var padding = 200
    Object.keys(MassAddressDict).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key + " " + MassAddressDict[key]);

        var recieverData = MassAddressDict[key]

        var senderInfo = combineSenderInfo();
        var receiverInfo = combineReceiverInfo(recieverData);

        var index = Object.keys(MassAddressDict).indexOf(key);
        

        if (index % 10 === 0){

            padding = padding + 20
            console.log("Padding increased to ", padding)
            
        } 
        printWindow.document.write('<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">');

        printWindow.document.write(senderInfo);
         printWindow.document.write('</div>');
        printWindow.document.write(receiverInfo);
        printWindow.document.write("<p style='padding-bottom: 200px'></p>")
    });
```

what I want to do is at every tenth item in the dictionary, increase the padding by say 20px. How can I implement this?

Comment: You keep setting the padding to `200` (then `20`). You need to move the variable declaration outside your forEach loop.

Comment: I believe `.forEach()` optionally passes in an index, you shouldn't need to work it out for yourself.

Comment: @ChrisG yea that was an error. it should be outside the .forEach()

Comment: @e.iluf Are you saying that on every 10th item, you want extra padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I think this will solve your problem

```js
    
    var padding = 200;
    Object.keys(MassAddressDict).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key + " " + MassAddressDict[key]);

        var recieverData = MassAddressDict[key]

        var senderInfo = combineSenderInfo();
        var receiverInfo = combineReceiverInfo(recieverData);

        var index = Object.keys(MassAddressDict).indexOf(key);

        if (index % 10 === 0){

            padding = padding + 20
            console.log("Padding increased to ", padding)
            
        } 
        printWindow.document.write('<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">');

        printWindow.document.write(senderInfo);
         printWindow.document.write('</div>');
        printWindow.document.write(receiverInfo);
        printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: ${padding}px'></p>`)
    });
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer. Just solving it in code makes it a spot-the-difference to see what has changed, and then the asker has to work out **why** that fixes the problem (Or they just copy-paste, and no one learns anything)

Comment: On the above solution, I have declared `padding` variable before the loop, then the available is persistence, and it increases when satisfy the condition.
And on this line 
`
printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: ${padding}px'></p>`)
`
I have written the element with the updated `padding` variable.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to get your padding out of your forEach, now it's resetting to 200 for each new object.

Then simply add your padding in your style (you can easily add a variable in a string in javascript using backticks and putting your var inside ${} `` `This is your var => ${myVar}` ``).

Your code should look like that :

```js
var padding = 200
Object.keys(MassAddressDict).forEach(function(key, index) {
    console.log(key + " " + MassAddressDict[key]);

    var recieverData = MassAddressDict[key]

    var senderInfo = combineSenderInfo();
    var receiverInfo = combineReceiverInfo(recieverData);

    if (index % 10 === 0){
        padding = padding + 20
        console.log("Padding increased to ", padding)
    } 
    printWindow.document.write('<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">');

    printWindow.document.write(senderInfo);
    printWindow.document.write('</div>');
    printWindow.document.write(receiverInfo);
    printWindow.document.write(`<p style='padding-bottom: ${padding}px'></p>`)
});
```

Comment: You don't need to keep finding `indexOf` inside of the for loop. The second parameter of the `forEach` callback is the index of the item.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AbirTaheer Yes you're right, I was focused on the padding thing but there sure is other ways to improve this code. I edited the answer to use the index given by the forEach.

Answer (score 0):

here is some way of the dynamic CSS style

```
  1 var div = document.getElementById('div1');
    
    // Clear Value
    div.setAttribute('style','');
      // OR
    div.removeAttribute('style');
    
    // Set Style / Append Style
  2  div.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';

  3  document.getElementById('#div1').style += "padding-top:40px";

  4  $("#div1").css("property",'value');

  5 Var Value=25;
     <div id='div1' style='padding: ${Value}px'></div>
```

you should read this for complete reference
https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use CSS and not JS. In this case, you need to use :nth-child();

Inside of nth-child you put the formula you want, in order to select the elements you want. In this case I use 3n+1. So the elements that are selected are:

3x0+1 = 1;

3x1+1 = 4;

3x2+1 = 7;

3x3+1 = 10;

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.item:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 0 20px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item"> item1 </div>
  <div class="item"> item2 </div>
  <div class="item"> item3 </div>
  <div class="item"> item4 </div>
  <div class="item"> item5 </div>
  <div class="item"> item6 </div>
  <div class="item"> item7 </div>
  <div class="item"> item8 </div>
  <div class="item"> item9 </div>
  <div class="item"> item10 </div>
</div>
```